# Localizar el radiobutton de una lista

Tags: radiobutton

En esta tabla, ¿como localizo el número de radiobutton pulsado?.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{accounts}}"><h8>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
           <span><input type="radio" name="cuentaSel" value = {{item.IBAN}} on-click="getRadioButton" class="call-md-2"> IBAN - {{item.IBAN}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <span class=verde >Saldo - {{item.balance}}</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Muy buenas. Esto que preguntas es algo escaso. Para poder responder bien a tu pregunta necesitamos saber que código tienes, que lenguaje o framework estas usando, que has buscado y por donde estás aproximadamente del desarrollo. Intenta editar tu pregunta, justo debajo de ella pone editar, y agrega el código que tienes, al menos la parte donde sale lo que necesitas, y lo que has probado para sacar el radiobutton. Un saludo.

Comment: Lo he conseguido con el Shadow.

Comment: Me alegro que lo consiguieras. Podrías responder a tu propia pregunta en el cuadro de abajo de Tu Respuesta para que así, quienes tengan el mismo problema, lo puedan encontrar. Un saludo.